# Untoggle Accumulation

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

http://jsfiddle.net/HT9Bx/426/  === My calendar (here sum-up with b1 b2 b3), and over him a Youtube Player. I want the events to take the place of the Youtube player (youtube display : none). So i used a toggle on youtube and the event. But when users click event 1 and after event 2, both appear !

```
<div id="youtubeEmbed" class="youtubeEmbed"></div>

<div id="event1"></div>
<div id="event2"></div>
<div id="event3"></div>

<div id="b1" class="b"></div>
<div id="b2"class="b"></div>
<div id="b3"class="b"></div>

.youtubeEmbed {   width:100px;   height:75px;    background-color:red;}

.b{    width:20px;    height:5px;    background-color:black;     margin:20px;}

#event1 {       width:100px;   height:75px;    background-color:blue;    display:none;}
#event2 {       width:100px;   height:75px;    background-color:blue;    display:none;}
#event3 {       width:100px;   height:75px;    background-color:blue;    display:none;}


$( "#b1" ).click(function() {
    $(".youtubeEmbed").toggle();
    $("#event1").toggle();
});

$( "#b2" ).click(function() {
    $(".youtubeEmbed").toggle();
    $("#event2").toggle();
});

$( "#b3" ).click(function() {
    $(".youtubeEmbed").toggle();
    $("#event3").toggle();
});
```

Comment: you need to clarify your question. What are you attempting to do/expected output and what are you getting currently

Comment: i just did it, thank you for the answer

Comment: @johnGazay if his answer worked, please select it as the answer below.

Comment: @LeonGaban No correct answer for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to put more effort to explain the issue, but for start, try this example:

```
$( '.b' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( 'div.event' ).not( 'div#' + $( this ).data( 'toggle' ) ).hide();
    $( 'div#' + $( this ).data( 'toggle' ) ).toggle();  
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HT9Bx/429/)

**EDIT**

Here is another try. Events will "replace" `youtubeEmbed` div on select, if no event is selected `youtubeEmbed` will be displayed.

```
$( '.b' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( 'div.event' ).not( 'div#' + $( this ).data( 'toggle' ) ).hide();
    $( 'div#' + $( this ).data( 'toggle' ) ).toggle();
    $( 'div.event:visible' ).length ? $( '#youtubeEmbed').hide() : $( '#youtubeEmbed').show();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HT9Bx/458/)

Comment: Thank, your solution is so close of my aim, the problem here is that the youtubeEmbed do not desapear. I just edit my question to help better understanding.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking for as your ids and classes don't match your code, but in order to make changes to CSS with JQuery use .css(); method, Example:

```
$("#id").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: Thank you, i rephrased the question